# GAE organizing data structure problem

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

Ok. I'm working with GAE. And i want create something like this:

I have types "group" "topic" "tag":

1. **each "group" can have as many
   "topics" as needed**
2. **each "topic" can have as many "tags"
   as needed**
3. **each "group" can have as many "tags"
   as needed**

it's something like circle.

right now i have something like this:

```
class TopicGroup(db.Model):
    value = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class Topic(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    group = db.ReferenceProperty(TopicGroup, 'group', 'topics', required=True)

class TopicTag(db.Model):
    topic = db.ReferenceProperty(Topic, 'topic', 'tags', required=True)
    group = db.ReferenceProperty(TopicGroup, 'group', 'tags', required=True)
    value = db.StringProperty(required=True)
```

but this is no good (in my model "topic" can have only one tag, but i nead "topic" to have as many tags as needed)

well i already have a crack in my head...  is there someone who could help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many-to-many joins can be implemented as join tables (or Relationship Models). In the solution below, there is a model that holds all of the tags that are applied to individual `Groups` (`GroupTags`) and a model that holds the tags that are applied to `Topics` (`TopicTags`).

Decoupling the `Tag` itself from references to the `Tag` allows you to do things like change the spelling of a tag without needing to update every `Group` or `Topic` to which that `Tag` is applied.

Also, this model takes good advantage of the fact that AppEngine creates automatic backreferences on entities that have other entities referencing them. In the models below, a Group entity will have a property called `topics` that is a query that will fetch all `Topic` entities who's `group` reference points to that `Group`.  Similarly, each `Group` gets a `tags` property from the `GroupsTags` model that gives it all of the `Tag` entities that belong to it. Every `Tag` entity gets a `groups` and `topics` property that is a query for all of the entities of those types that have the give Tag assigned, making searching by tag (a very typical operation) quite simple.

It's a very powerful and flexible approach to modeling systems such as yours.

```
class Group(db.Model):
    # All of my group-specific data here.

class Topic(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    group = db.ReferenceProperty(Group, collection='topics')
    # other topic-specific data here.

class Tag(db.Model):
    text = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class GroupTags(db.Model):
    group = db.ReferenceProperty(Group, collection='tags')
    tag = db.ReferenceProperty(Tag, collection='groups')

class TopicTags(db.Model):
    topic = db.ReferenceProperty(Topic, collection='tags')
    tag = db.ReferenceProperty(Tag, collection='topics')
```

Comment: Wow... Tnx a lot.. you save my day :) I'm just start to work with GAE.. so it's little hard for me. Anyway tnx again.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use a db.ListProperty with a type of db.Key. 
see: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html (section many to many)

Comment: The primary limitation of this approach is that a ListProperty is limited to 5000 values. Also, performing operations such as deleting all references to an entity referred to in such a way can be very difficult; you need to query for each entity that has the to-be-deleted key in its List and then update each List. This does not scale well to large numbers of entities.

Comment: Yes, but db.get(a_list) is much faster. So, it depend for what you use it. If a topic can have more than 1mega of keys, ok... but it little propable

Comment: Your point that doing a `get` on a list of keys is very efficient, so if the system writes infrequently and mostly does reads, then your solution has a meaningful advantage.

Comment: Sahid's solution is by far superior for cases like a list of tags. Deletion with a join table is no cheaper and only marginally simpler than deletion with a list of tags - and it scales no better.