# GAE Models: How to list child nodes in parent

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

Using Google App Engine in Python and references, you automatically get a back reference from the referenced object to the one you're dealing with. This is described very well in the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4004770/gae-organizing-data-structure-problem/4004869#4004869).

What I'd like to do is create a (simpler) one-to-many relationship, with each Group having a list of Tags, and each Tag belongs to only one Group. I picture it something like the following:

```
class Group(db.Model):
    # All of my group-specific data here.

class Tag(db.Model):
    text = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    group = db.ReferenceProperty(Group, collection='tags')
```

Assuming I understand everything correctly... In the above, you wind up with each `Group` having a `tags` property:

```
# Get the list of Tag objects that belong to a Group object
mytags = mygroup.tags
```

My question is, is there a "standard" way to include that information in the `Group` object? When looking at the data models, you can't see by looking at the `Group` object that it has a list of Tags that apply to it. I'd like to be able to define `Group,Tags` as something like

```
class Group(db.Model):
    # This should automatically be the same as the "tags" property that is
    # created for the Group model by the definition of the Tag model
    tags = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
    # All of my group-specific data here.

class Tag(db.Model):
    text = db.StringProperty(required=True)
    group = db.ReferenceProperty(Group, collection='tags', required=True)
    # Other tag specific information here (such as url, etc)
```

The idea being that I want to be able to see, when I look at the Group model, that it has a list of Tag objects as a property. It feels *unnatural* to me to have to look at the Tag model to know this information.

***Note:*** It may be worth noting that I plan on having the `Group` in question be the parent (for the Entity Group) of each of it's `Tag`s. Any time I modify a `Group`, I will be updating it completely, replacing all of it's `Tag`s with new ones, and I want to get the correct list of them for the given "version" of the `Group` I'm looking at.

The use cases for my data include:

- **Update groups** - create or update 6 groups. If create, then create the tags for the group. If update, completely replace the tags for the group (removing old ones) - happens every 5 minutes or so
- **Read recent groups** - get the 6-20 (undecided yet) most recently modified groups, no need to load their tags
- **Read single group** - get the information for a single group, including it's tags (each one will have between 10 and 20 tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you going to query your tags, will you be concerned only with tags from a particular entity group?  If that is the case, since you're going to put your `Tag` entities in a `Group` entity's entity group, the `ReferenceProperty` provides no real value.  You could instead use `tag_entity.key().parent()` to get the `Group` entity's key or `tag_entity.parent()` to get the `Group` entity itself.  You could then use a `ListProperty` on `Group` to store the key_names of the tag entities (which I presume will be the actual 'tag').

Since you are replacing all of a group's tags any time the `Group` entity is updated, have you considered using a `ListProperty` to store your tags on directly on `Group` entity.  Or, storing a list of tag key_names directly on `Group`.  Either approach would make fetching all tags for a group quite easy and efficient.

Comment: I added a little more detail to my question, including the use cases and the fact that tags have more information than just their text. I have considered storing the ListProperty of tag ids with the group. The problem then (iiuc) is that, when retrieving the tags for a group, I'd need to use an "IN (ids)" clause, which results in multiple database hits. If the information is stored with the tags, then I can use a "WHERE group_id = :group_id" type query.

Comment: @RHSeeger Actually if you store the list of entity ids or names then you can very efficiently fetch them all directly using Model.get_by_key_name (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_key_name).  For tags I like to use the (case normalized) tag as the Tag entity key_name, since it gives you useful data without needing to fetch the tag entity.  You can also efficiently delete (ie no fetches / queries) the existing tags this way, since you can easily build the tag entities keys using db.Key.from_path.

Comment: @Robert: Do you know what the actual implementation of get_by_key_name is? From what I've read about similar capabilities, it seems like it will hit the database once for each key... much like doing a 'key in (list of keys)' sql query.

Comment: @RHSeeger, No it is not the same as an 'IN' query.  The key names are converted to keys, then a single batch get is done.  The SDK is open source, I would encourage you to explore it as the comments are very helpful.  http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py#1191

Comment: @Robert - Thank you very much for the information. Oddly enough, I'm running up against a problem where the lack of the parent->child relationship in the parent appears to be causing problems (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6244543/gae-model-loses-track-of-parent-child-relationship). Converting the code to use a parent->child relationship in the model (rather than child<-parent, if that makes sense) may help me avoid my strange problem.

Comment: @RHSeeger, That issue is a 'quirk' of how ReferenceProperty adds the 'back reference', you shouldn't see that happen on production.

Answer (score 1):

Having a ListProperty as you suggest will, as you probably realize, mean you're keeping two references redundantly, which isn't necessary. A simpler approach would be to simply note in a comment that describes the relationship.

If you're going to use entity groups anyway, though, you don't need the `ReferenceProperty` or the `ListProperty`. You can fetch the `Tag` children of a `Group` with `Tag.all().ancestor(my_group)`.

Another option would be to store the tags as a list of strings. Additional information can be stored in `Tag` entities with `key_name`s set to the tag name. You can then fetch all the tag entities referenced by an object with `Tag.get_by_key_name(my_entity.tags)`. This is mostly useful if you usually only need the tag names and only sometimes retrieve the full data - otherwise you may as well stick with a `ReferenceProperty` or an Entity Group.

Answer (score 0):

[modeling in appengine](http://daily.profeth.de/2008/04/er-modeling-with-google-app-engine.html)

## one-to-many using parent in that will come in handy for you

you can also consider other examples

Comment: The parent property of an entity is used for entity grouping, to keep data stored together and allow for transactions. Using it to mean something other than it's defined as meaning seems like a bad idea to me.