# GAE: Model loses track of parent->child relationship

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

I'm having what seems like a very strange problem with an Entity relationship in the google app engine data store. I'm work on a Python/GAE webapp (learning exercise), the full code to which can be found on [sourceforge](http://rhs-galleries.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rhs-galleries/?pathrev=49).

- I have 2 models:

  - [Gallery](http://rhs-galleries.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rhs-galleries/google-app-engine/trunk/app/models/gallery.py?revision=49&view=markup&pathrev=49) - a search term and (indirectly) a list of photos
  - [Photo](http://rhs-galleries.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rhs-galleries/google-app-engine/trunk/app/models/photo.py?revision=47&view=markup&pathrev=49) - information about a photo, plus the gallery it belongs to (collection_index='photos')
- I have an ingestion process that creates galleries and adds photos to them
- I have a page that reads a gallery from the datastore and uses the ".photos" attribute of that Gallery instance to get the list of photos in it

Now this is where the weird part comes in... **If I change a file (any file I've tested on) or even just update the timestamp of the file (ie, so it gets reloaded)... the ".photos" attribute of galleries starts failing.** For example, if I try to load the [page for the "flowers" gallery](http://localhost:8080/gallery/flowers):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Applications\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 700, in __call__ handler.get(*groups)
  File "C:\Eclipse-Workspace\galleries-google\app\views\gallery.py", line 33, in get for photo in gallery.photos:
AttributeError: 'Gallery' object has no attribute 'photos'
```

I can restart the webapp, I can restart the app launcher and then start the webapp. The problem persists regardless of this. It seems I need to force the datastore to "remember" the connection in some way

```
# Reading the list of photos for a given gallery via the Photo entity
# This seems to force the datastore to "remember" the connection between the two
from google.appengine.ext import db
import pprint
from app.models.gallery import Gallery
from app.models.photo import Photo

gallery = Gallery.get_by_key_name('candy')
print("Gallery: " + gallery.search_term)
q = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Photo WHERE gallery = :1", gallery )
photos = q.fetch(20)

for photo in photos :
    print("\tphoto: " + photo.getUrl('original'))
```

or by re-ingesting all the data from scratch (though I suppose even just re-ingesting a single gallery would do).

**Does anyone have any thoughts as to what might be causing this?** Any help would be appreciated.

Notes:

- This is in the dev environment. I haven't gotten to the point where it's worth registering it as a webapp on the real servers yet.
- Oddly enough, I recently asked a question on how to [How to list child nodes in parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232092/gae-models-how-to-list-child-nodes-in-parent) in GAE... since I really wanted the information to exist in the parent model definition. Ironic that it's (apparently) a lack of that information in the parent that's causing a problem now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after much digging around, I believe I found an answer...

- When a file is modified (the timestamp changes), the app engine invalidates the compiled/cached files it has
- When the `Photo` class is defined, it adds a property to the `Gallery based on the collection of ids it has for them`
- When it needs the `Gallery` class, the app engine reloads the code for it... because it's definition was invalidated by a file being modified
- Since it doesn't know it needs the `Photo` class, it doesn't load that file, so the "new instance" of the `Gallery` class doesn't have the property that should be created for it's collection

My first solution was to add a dependency on the `Photo` file in the `Gallery` file.

```
from app.models.photo import Photo
```

The *problem* with this is that it creates a circular dependency between the two files (since Photo already needs to know about Gallery in order to have a list of them). While it worked, I was told that Python has "problems" with circular dependencies, and it's probably not a good thing to do; it may come back to bite me later.

**The solution I wound up going with was to have the __init.py file for the package in question include a dependency for both files. As such, any time either one of the files is needed, both will be loaded.**

Comment: You're exactly right about the cause of your problem; the `photo` attribute is added to `Gallery` when the ReferenceProperty is instantiated, which happens in the definition of `Photo`.  Python doesn't do well with circular imports, so you might want to rethink the solution.  One solution: put both model definitions in the same file.  The other thing to note is that to use the results of the `Gallery.photos` query you'll need `Photo` defined so it will need imported anyway, in other words clearing .pyc files after changes to `Gallery` on dev will fix this too.

Comment: @Robert: Clearing the pyc files doesn't fix it, since it never loads the Photo class until you get the photos from a gallery, which you can't do if the gallery doesn't know it has photos. What I wound up doing was putting an import for both files in the __init__.py file for the package. As such, whenever either of the files (gallery, photo) are loaded, both are.